# Update search.max_buckets in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have a doubt about update search.max_buckets, because I have some warning due that an aggregation creates too many buckets, so my doubt is if I update this value over 10000, I will improve the performance. Now I have some times that I would like to improve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More buckets means more resources used when doing that aggregation. If you have very powerful nodes in your cluster, a higher max_bucket value should be ok.

Answer (score 6):

Do note that search.max_buckets is a safety soft-limit designed to prevent bad aggregations from hurting nodes. So be careful about making the limit too high. If you're tripping the limit often it might mean your aggregations need to be reconsidered or made smaller.

Comment: PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search.max_buckets": 20000
  }
}

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a config file?

Comment: Yes, add search.max_buckets: 20000 in elasticsearch.yml and restart your nodes.